# How to add graphic into a label template in Word 2011?

Tags: microsoft-word, template

I need to create labels in Microsoft Word with two company logos.

I have created an image for the side of the label and thought I could watermark it, but it only appears in the middle of 1 label.

It has to be in word because another person is creating labels for there meeting.

**How to add graphic into a label template in Word 2011?**

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!  Can you please descibe a little bit better what your problem is? Is it word or is it how to create a label (what do you mean with that?).  Perhaps you can show us an picture or screenshot?  Add it to your question and delete the ! One with more reputation can activate it for you ...

Answer (score 1):

To Add 2 images on a label template, in all the label cases do the following:

---

## 1. Labels template

Go in the menu "Tools", and select "labels"

---

## 2. Include image in the address box { }

Click in the address box on top, and then press "Command + F9" (Control + F9).

You'll see 2 brace field {}

[image: Include images in Microsoft Words]

## 3. Type INCLUDEIMAGE and the path

Between the field braces {}, write INCLUDEIMAGE and then between quotes add the path of your image. No space needed.

**It should look like this for Mac:**

*{INCLUDEIMAGE"file:///Users/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/image-name.png"}*

**I'm not sure if you need the quotes for Windows**

*{INCLUDEIMAGE c:\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxxxx\image-name.png}*

**For your second image, do the same thing.**

They will be added next to each others unless they really don't fit.

**Don't forget to check the box "Full page of the same label"** and o select the kind of label you will print on the label section, by clicking the button "Options."

Press OK when you're done.

---

## 4. Update the page

Now you'll see your page is blank like this.

[image: blank page labels]

**You need to update it.
To do this, select all (use Command +A, or Control+A), and then press F9.**

All your little labels should get updated with the 2 images.

[image: 2 logo per labels Microsoft words]

---

> ## Quick trick to get file path of the image
>
> Simply drag that image in your browser window, and copy the path in
> the address bar!